# importing jQuery with jade(with node.js + express)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I got question about jade. I imported like follow, but it seems ignored.(When I inspect source with Chrome, can not find those resources :<)

extends layout

```
head block append
  link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/chat.css')
  script(src="/socket.io/socket.io.js")
  script(src="/javascripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js")
  script(src="/javascripts/chat.js")
```

How can I import these scripts?

Thanks !

//===============
This is what I get when 'page source' function of Chrome browser.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Chat Sample</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Chat</h1>
    <label for="userName">User name: (Hit Enter)</label>
    <input id="userName" type="text" size="30">
    <span id="feedBack"></span>
    <p> </p>
    <div id="msgWindow" class="shadow">
    </div>
    <p> </p>
    <div>
        <br>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <select id="users" style="width: 100px"></select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input id="msg" type="text" style="width: 600px" disabled="true">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

However, css file also does not applied to the page. I can get full contents of file, when I approach with url like `http://localhost:3000/javascripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js`.

I have changed jquery version//

//===========Edit

Follow is the error. I can not understand why `head` is unexpected//

```
Warning: Unexpected block "head"  on line 3 of /Users/juneyoungoh/Documents/Nodejs/ChatSample/views/chat.jade. This block is never used. This warning will be an error in v2.0.0
```

FYI, this is `layout.jade`

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title= title
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
  body
    block content
```

Comment: Right syntax, check your serve-static logic

Comment: @trquoccuong I am following this site. https://vijayannadi.wordpress.com/tutorials/sample-chat-app-using-nodejs-socketio/ I have double checked what does described. Is there any hint for this issue?

Comment: app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'))); Do you have folder like <your project>/javascripts/jquery/jquery-1.7.2.min.js

Comment: @trquoccuong I can see full contents of 'jquery-1.7.2.min.js' when I put `localhost:3000/javascripts/jquery/jquery-1.7.2.min.js` or chat.css. However, according to chrome inspector, the page still does not include `js` meta files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never appended a block, but jade-lang.com is mentioning following syntax:

```
extends layout

block append head
  link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/chat.css')
  script(src="/socket.io/socket.io.js")
  script(src="/javascripts/jquery/jquery-1.7.2.min.js")
  script(src="/javascripts/chat.js")
```

http://jade-lang.com/reference/inheritance/

Comment: Thanks for reference. But I can not still import those files. I edited the post.

Comment: Got Error ! Thanks! :D bbbbb

Comment: Solution summary for my case is added as a comment below

Comment: Nice to hear that you was able to fix your problem. Feel free to mark your own post as solution, cause it is more relevant for other people who may read this question.

Comment: I can't comment on your answer, cause i need 50 reputations, so i write here: I tested it and your solution works fine with the head-Tag but note that blocks regularly do not convert their names to html tags. So normally you should define `block head` inside the `head`-Element

Comment: Thanks for your advice

Answer (score 0):

I got the hint from Jannik's comment. Maybe a version problem.
In conclusion, I edited `layout.jade`.

from

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title= title
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
  body
    block content
```

to

```
doctype html
html
  block head
    title= title
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
  body
    block content
```

I added `block` keyword.

FYI, I am using

- npm ver.2.12.1
- node ver.0.10.23
- express ver.3.4.7

and package.json like

```
{
  "name": "application-name",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "3.4.7",
    "jade": "*"
  }
}
```

Thanks for your help! :D